# AngularJS ui-mask Adding a MAX and MINIMUM for a currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the official AngularJS UI-Mask https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask and trying to figure out how I can create a mask for currency USD.

I want the user to be able to put $00.01 to like $9,000,000.00 or whatever the desired max is.

I currently have: `<input type="text" ng-model="greeting" ui-mask="$99.99" class="form-control input-lg" style="width:50%" />`

That limits me to $99...

Here is a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ErV11uGVxJFmD24K2jk?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use input number.

```
     <input type="number" min="0.99" max="9000000.00" ng-model="greeting" 
     class="form-control input-lg" style="width:50%" />
```

Comment: That allows an E. I do not want users to be able to input an E

Comment: U can use the filter currency